# Graph library in Lua

Tags: graph, lua

Is there a Lua library (or with Lua bindings) to build graphs (directed/undirected), with traversal algorithms, connectivity tests, and other basic graph operations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [LuaGRAPH](http://luagraph.luaforge.net/index.html) library is a Lua binding to GraphViz that might suit your needs.

> #### Features
>
> - Define graphs using Lua syntax elements (tables, functions)
> - Layout and render graphs
> - Iterators for subgraphs, nodes and edges
> - Set and get for all graphviz attributes for graphs, nodes and edges
> - Set and get user defined properties (even methods) to any graph object